# FCM iOS notification with different bundleId and APNS key

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send a push notification via FCM. I have 2 apps for the one project(customer and driver). I have added them in the same Firebase project

I am using APNS key in the Apple account, so I have used the same TeamId and APNS key in the firebase project. Now question is how can I send the push to each apps? How can I specify the app in FCM, Can we specify the bundleId in the "topic" or some other key?
I am currently checking with cURL and Postman you can provide answer for this or on Node side

If we are using node-apn we can specify the bundleId in the "topic" key also it is asking for KeyId/TeamId.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to separate the app. Firebase manage everything when you add new app under any project you have to download the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file and add into your project. For each separate project there is different `GoogleService-Info.plist` and that file is configure with your xcode project and generate FCM token for each device.

You can test your notification from postman to using `POST` method

> `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

> Headers

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AAAAueCg8bE.......YOUR FIREBASE KEY
```

Payload

```
{
   "notification": {
      "category": "myNotificationCategory",
       "title": "Ticket Confirm",
       "subtitle": "Rajkot",
       "body": "Testing iOS App Notification",
       "mutable-content" : 1,
       "attachments": "www.google.com",
       "sound" : "default"
   },
   "registration_ids": [
       "YOUR FCM TOKEN"
   ]
}
```

If your response is success you get `message_id` in response. That's it.